# How to add a prop to a child component already receiving props via the spread operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-component, react-functional-component

I'm not sure if this is a TypeScript issue, or if it's more of a React props behavior question, or if it's simply me messing up ES6 destructuring.

I have a ParentComponent whose props are type ParentProps, and a ChildComponent which also has the same type. The ChildComponent consumes the same props, except for ONE prop which I now need to redefine (or if that's not possible, add a new one).

For this example let's say ParentProps is just `buttonName: string` and `doSomething: (text: string) => void`

I thought I could add to an object destructuring by spreading one object, then adding property: value after a comma, ie: `{...props, additionalProp: doSomething}` But that doesn't seem to work: `Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.` **Can anyone chime in on what my issue is here and what I'm doing wrong?**

```js
const ParentComponent: FC<ParentProps> = memo(function ParentComponent({
  ...props
}) {
  function doSomething(text) {
    console.log("did the thing", text)
  }

  return <ChildComponent {...props, doSomething: doSomething} />   // <----here's the problem
})

export function ChildComponent(props: ParentProps) {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.doSomething(props.buttonName)}>{props.buttonName}</button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...or if it's simply me messing up ES6 destructuring.

```js
   return <ChildComponent {...props} doSomething={doSomething} /> //  do this
```

You have to destructure an object (or array). You were confusing the JSX-property brackets with the brackets used to declare an object.

The example above will also overwrite a potentially existing property `props.doSomething`. React-props will overwrite previously defined props. However, it would be better if you were explicit about this change instead of implicitly overwriting it.